# Two urls directed to same file

Tags: nginx

I need two urls to point to the same php file using nginx. How do I do this?

example:

```
api.example.com/users => /var/www/public_html/index.php/users
example.com/api/users => /var/www/public_html/index.php/users
```

I'm trying:

```
location ~ ^/api/(.*)$ {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$1;
}
```

This adds '/api/' to the request url. How can this be prevented?

Comment: any reason not to do this on the back end by creating a softlink for the directory?

Comment: I'm using api.example.com for firefox and other webkit browsers. I wasn't able to use that url in IE9 because of some of the CORS restrictions. So now I'm trying it this way.

Comment: Is that a typo? You have `$s1` instead of `$1`.